# Need to filter fieldvalue from the below

Tags: angular

I want to filter the fieldvalue and the length of the filedvalue character greater than 3 from the below array. Please help with this

```
[
    {
        "fieldName": "",
        "fieldValue": "",
        "OrderbyFieldName": "",
        "OrderbyDesc": false
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "Selection",
        "fieldValue": "b",
        "OrderbyFieldName": "",
        "OrderbyDesc": false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do just that.

```
const filteredData = data.filter(item => item.fieldValue?.length >= 3);
```